# Android EditText combined with InputFilter vs TextWatcher

Tags: android, performance

Basically I would like to know more in depth difference and usage scenario for `InputFilter` and `TextWatcher`.

As per the docs:
**`InputFilter`**: InputFilters can be attached to Editables to constrain the changes that can be made to them.

**`TextWatcher`:** When an object of a type is attached to an Editable, its methods will be called when the text is changed. **So it can be used to constrain the change correct me if I am wrong**

**Which one is better? and why?** My scenario is I need an EditText with minimum 6 characters after decimal point in it.

Comment: see `InputFilter` documentation and see its `"Known Indirect Subclasses"`, do the same with a `TextWatcher`

Comment: @pskink after doing that what I noticed is InputFilter is used to listen key events and constrain changes while Textwatcher is used with view notify the changes...please tell me my observation is wrong or right? If i missed something please add to it.

Comment: yes, your observation is right

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`TextWatcher` is used to be notified whenever user types.
`InputFilter` decides what can be typed.

For example,
Suppose I want to allow the user to enter temperature. This temperature has to be all numbers and can only contain two digits after decimal. If you look closely, I need both `TextWatcher` and `InputFilter`.

`InputFilter` would allow only numbers.

```
final InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[]
                { DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(true, true) };
textView.setFilters(filters);
```

Now, this would allow numbers with more than two digits after decimal. Why? Because `InputFilter` only restricts what keys can be typed. Here's when `TextWatcher` comes in.

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // you need this to avoid loops
    // or your stack will overflow
    if(!textView.hasWindowFocus() || textView.hasFocus() || s == null){
        return;
    }
    // Now you can do some regex magic here to see 
    // if the user has entered a valid string
    // "\\d+.\\d{6,}" for your case

}
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation with an example. From your answer and comment from @pskink I noticed is InputFilter is used to listen key events to constrain user input. While TextWatcher is used observe the change and then restrict the user accordingly.