# How to enforce editText not to start with space

Tags: android

I have a edit Text.I don't want the first letter to be space.
If user hit the space as first letter cursor should not move.

Answer (score 10):

Create a TextWatcher like this

```
public class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private EditText editText;

    public MyTextWatcher(EditText editText) {
        this.editText = editText;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        String text = editText.getText().toString();
        if (text.startsWith(" ")) {
            editText.setText(text.trim());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
}
```

And add this to your EditText

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(editText));
```

Comment: @jankigadhiya Why not? Suppose the text is " " (Just one space). In the case, length of text is 1 so `isEmpty()` will return `false`. But `text.trim()` will remove the space and length will be 0 so `isEmpty()` will be true.

Comment: @jankigadhiya Done :)

Comment: this code will always remove every text from the text box

Comment: @Shruti How? It will only remove only white spaces at start without effecting any other text. Can your explain why do you think it'll remove every text?

Comment: @Rehan Your solution do not cover all cases f.e. 
1. user write "test";
2. user put cursor at start;
3. user add as many space chars as he want;
To solve it you can change your conditions.

Comment: @ArturSzymański Updated :)

Answer (score 4):

Basing on the first answer by Luca:

```
TextWatcher mWatcher = new TextWatcher() { 
@Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
 if (myEditText.getText().toString().startsWith(" ")) 
myEditText.setText(""); 
}
```

Here I changed `equals` to `startsWith`
Than set it

Comment: Simplest answer!!

Comment: Yes, this works fine. But after writing some text, if you go back to first position and type space, then the edit text clears.

Comment: Thank you, It's Working this solution

Answer (score 1):

```
TextWatcher myWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
 @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (myEditText.getText().toString().equals(" "))
              myEditText.setText("");
        }
```

and then

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(myWatcher);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `InputFilter` to your `Edittext` by following method. It will restrict user to enter space in starting.

```
 InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                                   Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            if (source.length()>0 &&Character.isWhitespace(source.charAt(0)) && yourEditText.getText().toString().length()==0) {
                return "";
            }
            return source;
        }
    };
yourEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```

> `InputFilter` is more reliable in terms of  performance as compared to `TextWatcher` in this scenario. You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33855940/3817374 for more detailed informarion.

Comment: This filters out the first space. But it also disallows spaces after writing some letters

Comment: @JainamJhaveri : Thanks for pointing out bug. I had missed one condition. Have updated answer. Please check it out and let me know if still not work for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37966063/4151080 Rehan's answer worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Add an if else condition to check the first letter

```
if(EditText.getText().charAt(0)!=" "){
//COOL!
}
else
{
//ERROR!
}
```

Make sure that it is run on the ui thread

Comment: It's about `EditText` not `TextView`..!!

Comment: oops! anyways, corrected it now... But seriously, I don't think there was any need for the downvote.

Comment: This won't work either.. He don't want the space as the first character @Luca Nicoletti's answer is correct at some point..!!